# Lsb as hard core predicate in a sign-hash scheme

Tags: randomness, hard-core-predicate

Given a random oracle and a deterministic signature scheme.

Is the following $hc(x)$ an hardcore predicate of $H(SIG_k(x))$ ?

$$hc(x)=lsb(H(SIG_k(x)))$$

How would I get to think about this? I saw a few academic papers that mention this strategy. I don't understand why that can be a valid hard-core predicate.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Assuming that the one-way function here is $SIG_k(\cdot)$, the predicate defined is not hard-core: it is easy to compute $hc(x)$ given the value of $SIG_k(x)$ (as everyone has access to the oracle $H$). Could you provide links to the papers you mention?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1607.01341.pdf page 26

Comment: The only claim I came across was that the LSB is a *random* bit (in Page 27), which it is.